# RequestError: TransportError(400, {u'line': 1, u'root_cause': [{u'reason': u'no [query] registered for [filtered]

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am using Elasticsearch as backend for haystack in my Django project. I have gone through the Haystack official document  and various other sites, But when i search it throws a traceback error with TransportError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'no [query] registered for [filtered]'). I also downgraded the elasticsearch backend version to 1. But the errors remains same:

```
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
RequestError: TransportError(400, {u'line': 1, u'root_cause': [{u'reason': u'no [query] registered for [filtered]', u'type': u'parsing_exception', u'line': 1, u'col': 24}], u'type': u'parsing_exception', u'reason': u'no [query] registered for [filtered]', u'col': 24})
```

Comment: please share your ElasticSearch version